# TypeError for definied variable in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to make a music player that allows a song to be put into the shell and is then played however, I'm having an issue with a type error in `class Notes():` and I can't figure out why.

```
import winsound
import time

length = 125

class Notes():
    def processNote(note):
        if(note == 'C'):return Notes.processNote(262)
        if(note == 'D'):return Notes.processNote(294)
        if(note == 'D5'):return Notes.processNote(587)
        if(note == 'A'):return Notes.processNote(440)
        if(note == 'Ab'):return Notes.processNote(415)
        if(note == 'G'):return Notes.processNote(392)
        if(note == 'F'):return Notes.processNote(349)
        if(note == 'B'):return Notes.processNote(247)
        if(note == 'Bb'):return Notes.processNote(233)
song = "CCCCCCCCCCCD"
noteList = list(song)
print(noteList)

for note in noteList:
    print("Doing ", note)
    frequency = Notes.processNote(note)
    winsound.Beep(frequency, length)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Tester.py", line 27, in <module>
    winsound.Beep(frequency, length)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

Comment: I believe you just mean `return 262` and so on; currently you are calling your function twice, and the second time always returns `None` because you are passing it an integer your function only handles strings.

Comment: It seems like your `.processNote` method returns None.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise the fix was that simple thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the function `processNote()` returns `None` for any valid input, because you are calling it twice instead of just returning the value. It may be helpful to look at how your code will be processed to understand why this happens:

Imagine `processNote()` is called with the note value `"C"`. That will match the first `if` statement and it will return **the result of calling `processNote()` with the value 262**. Since there's no if statement that catches 262 in the `processNote()` function, it returns `None` (because this is the default for Python functions), so the `frequency` variable ends up being `None`.

You can solve this rather simply, by just returning the literal value:

```
def processNote(note):
    if note == 'C':
        return 262
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

And if I can say something, instead of

```
class Notes():
    def processNote(note):
        if(note == 'C'):return Notes.processNote(262)
        if(note == 'D'):return Notes.processNote(294)
        if(note == 'D5'):return Notes.processNote(587)
        (thousands IFs)
```

You could use the python dictionary and create mapping:

```
class Notes():
    def processNote(note):
        signature_to_freq = {'C': 262, 'D': 294, 'D5': 587,
                            'B': 247}
        return signature_to_freq[note]
```

Comment: Well it's also better (easier) to change the return of the function. Edited.

Comment: Oh that's a much tidier way of writing it. I'll try to swap that in thank you.